# Вывести запись где id =null или 6

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

[image: table]Нужно сделать выборку из таблицы где у записи поле id = 7 или null.
Примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE event_category_id in (NULL,7);
```

Но этот пример не рабочий, выводятся только записи с id = 7.
Такое решение не подойдет:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE event_categoey_id = 7 or event_category_id is null;
```

Есть ли ещё способы вывести запись где id = null или 7?

Вот код, с помощью которого я пытаюсь получить данные записи(ruby), cat_id есть массив([null,7,8,9])

```
def get_by_range(cat_id) 
  Event.where('event_category_id in (?)',cat_id)
end
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59825/discussion-on-question-by-maksim-chanturia----id-null--6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Такое решение не подойдет:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM table WHERE event_categoey_id = 7 or event_category_id is null;
> ```

Напротив, **только оно по-хорошему и подойдёт**. Дело в том, что в SQL, согласно стандарту, `NULL` не равен `NULL`*, поэтому многое из того, что вы ожидаете, работать не может в принципе.

И вы зря заморачиваетесь с SQL-фрагментами. У Rails весьма умный составитель запросов. Не пользуйтесь SQL без крайней необходимости.

ActiveRecord в Rails прекрасно обрабатывает запрос с условием на множество значений (в форме массива) в поле без явного SQL. Он отделяет условие на `IS NULL`, а остальное отводит в `IN`.

```rb
puts Image.where(id: [7, 8, nil, 9]).to_sql
# SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE (
#   "images"."id" IN (7, 8, 9)
#     OR "images"."id" IS NULL
# )
```

И более того! Он спокойно воспринимает даже диапазоны внутри массивов, отводя их в `OR`...`BETWEEN`:

```rb
puts Image.where(id: [7, 8, nil, 9, 13..15]).to_sql
# SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE (
#   ("images"."id" IN (7, 8, 9) OR "images"."id" IS NULL)
#   OR "images"."id" BETWEEN 13 AND 15
# )
```

---

** это ломает многим мозг и соответствие оператора равенства `=` и включения `IN` [определению отношения эквивалентности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), ну да ладно*

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно сделать выборку из таблицы где у записи поле id = 7 или null.

```
WHERE COALESCE(id,7)=7
```

> Вот код, с помощью которого я пытаюсь получить данные записи(ruby), cat_id есть массив([null,7,8,9])

```
WHERE COALESCE(id,7) IN (7,8,9)
```